# How to query all values from 1rst table and fill with 2nd table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry if my question isn't clear at first.

I have those 3 tables:

```
Table A:
ID  |   DATE_CREATED

Table B:
ID  |   DATE_CREATED

TABLE C:
ID  |   DATE_CREATED
```

What I want is getting all dates from Table A when ID A and B are the same:

```
SELECT A.DATE_CREATED 
FROM A, B 
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

Now what I don't get is how to get all the dates from Table C and put them in the query above so that only the ones that don't exist in that query are put in it.

So if the query outputs

```
ID  |   DATE_CREATED
1   |        2010
2   |        2009
3   |        2008
```

And table C contains

```
ID  |   DATE_CREATED
1   |        2017
2   |        2005
3   |        2003
4   |        2007
5   |        2010
```

My final result should be

```
ID  |   DATE_CREATED
1   |        2010
2   |        2009
3   |        2008
4   |        2007
5   |        2010
```

Thank you for reading my question! I am aware that this might question might already have been answered, as it is basic, but even by reading some similar questions my brain isn't able to process how to do it. I guess it's with a left join or something like that from what I read, but I don't get how it works even by checking examples and checking those join graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` statements and it will be much easier:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.ID, C.ID), COALESCE(A.DATE_CREATED, C.DATE_CREATED)
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
  FULL JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ID != C.ID
```

Comment: Don't forget to alias those COALESCE() columns. Otherwise they won't be able to be referenced.

Comment: I've used your method, works like I wanted, thanks! Coalesce does exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
WITH ab as (
      SELECT A.ID, A.DATE_CREATED 
      FROM A JOIN
           B 
           ON A.ID = B.ID
     )
SELECT ab.*
FROM ab
UNION ALL
SELECT c.ID, c.DATE_CREATED
FROM c
WHERE c.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM ab);
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify:

You want to display

```
A.ID, A.DATE_CREATED
```

or if there are no matches between A and B's ID fields then you want to display

```
C.ID, C.DATE_CREATED
```

So, you've already figured out how to get the first bit:

```
SELECT  A.ID, A.DATE_CREATED
FROM    A
INNER JOIN  B
ON  A.ID = B.ID
```

To add to the other 2 answers, here's how I'd do it old-school with temp tables:

```
SELECT  A.ID, A.DATE_CREATED
INTO    #tmpA
FROM    A
INNER JOIN  B
ON  A.ID = B.ID

SELECT  #tmpA.ID , #tmpA.DATE_CREATED
FROM    #tmpA
UNION SELECT    C.ID, C.DATE_CREATED
FROM    C
LEFT JOIN   #tmpA
ON  C.ID = #tmpA.ID
WHERE   #tmpA.ID IS NULL
```